# I dont want to use Video Poster

Tags: javascript, php, html

I don't want to use video poster, and nothing is displaying from the video until user clicks on play. How can I get a screenshot from video to display just not to make the thumbnail empty.

```
<video id="player1" width="640" height="360" style="max-width:100%;" poster="<?php echo $domain_root;?>/images/<?php echo $value['poster'];?>" preload="none" controls playsinline webkit-playsinline>
    <source src="<?php echo $domain_root;?>/images/<?php echo $value['btitle'];?>" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="<?php echo $domain_root;?>/images/<?php echo $value['btitle'];?>" type="video/ogg">
    <track srclang="en" kind="subtitles" src="<?php echo $domain_root;?>/mediaelement.vtt">
    <track srclang="en" kind="chapters" src="<?php echo $domain_root;?>/chapters.vtt">
</video>
```

Comment: Don't use. I think the title is not clear. By the way, Poster is a\ URL indicating a poster frame to show until the user plays or seeks. If this attribute isn't specified, nothing is displayed until the first frame is available; then the first frame is shown as the poster frame.

Comment: how will use the first frame as the poster frame please

Answer (score 0):

you can use some js library **like** [popcorn.capture](https://github.com/rwaldron/popcorn.capture/tree/master/src)

**example:** captures the image from 10th second of video and creates poster image :

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b3j5g7j7/)

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://cdn.popcornjs.org/code/dist/popcorn.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/popcorn.capture.js"></script>
</head>
<body  onload="myFunction()">

  <div id="unmoved-fixture">
        <video height="180" width="300" id="video-target">
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"></source>
        </video>
  </div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
   var $pop = Popcorn( "#video-target" ),
    poster;

    $pop.capture({
    at: 10 // captures the image from 10th second of video.
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

after all take a look of this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/gdp00x2s) and this in [github](https://github.com/codepo8/videograbber)

Comment: This is great, but the video player disappear ,how am i gonna fix that